# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost"

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, psycopg2

Got Error while doing docker-compose up.

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

docker-compose.yml:-

```
version: '3'

services:
  dcs_web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB:dcmDB'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER:postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD:admin'

volumes:
  db-data:
```

In App config.ini:

```
[DEFAULT]
DB_NAME = user
DB_PASSWORD = admin
DB_USER = postgres
DB_HOST = localhost
DB_PORT = 5433
DEBUG = True
```

I have gone throught '/var/lib/postgresql/data' location 'listen adress = *' is there . Dont know how to deal with this.

Comment: VVK kumar states below that his problem never got solved. The "already answered" box points to a solution that does not use docker-compose. So I am adding this comment to clarify the steps for using docker-compose in this scenario.

The answer from @bug is partially correct: the host has to be the service name `db`. However, this is not sufficient because Kumar is trying to connect via port 5433 while postgres is listening to port 5432.

The ports section of the YAML only connects local ports to container ports.To make pg listen on port 5433, add `command: postgres -p 5433` to service db.

Answer (score 10):

Each container in Docker is a separate host, which means that you can't reach Postgres from `dcs_web` using `localhost`, you have to use the hostname of the Postgres container, which by default is the name of the service defined in the Docker Compose file, in your case: `db`.

Replace `localhost` with `db` in your `config.ini` and it should work.

Comment: I did they way u said but got error. sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "db" (1XX.XX.XX.X) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

Comment: That's probably because Postgres is still starting up when the app tries to connect to it. It's best practice to use tools like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to wait for a service to startup. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) you can find more details.

Comment: But i am getting the logs like ' 2019-11-28 06:00:45.801 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections'  but after this only got the above error.

Comment: | /entrypoint.sh:/app/wait-for-it.sh: /bin/sh^M:bad interpreter: No such file or directory
|/entrypoint.sh: line 39:/app/wait-for-it.sh: Success
| 2019-11-28 06:22:35.878UTC[1]LOG:listening on IPv4 address"0.0.0.0",port 5432
| 2019-11-28 06:22:35.878UTC[1]LOG:listening on IPv6 address "::",port 5432
| 2019-11-28 06:22:38.217UTC[1]LOG:listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
| 2019-11-28 06:22:38.859UTC[24]LOG:database system was shut down at 2019-11-28 06:13:19 UTC
| 2019-11-28 06:22:38.911UTC[1]LOG:database system is ready to accept connections
|exited with code 127

Comment: ohhhh god after hours with chatgpt, this solved it.